# gdb call to malloc fails (iOS)

Tags: ios, gdb, call

I'm using gdb (release 1708 from radare.org) on iOS 6.0.1 to debug an unknown app. For some reason I want to allocate memory, which should work via "call (char*)malloc(size)". I already browsed a lot of samples using such calls (for instance [here](http://www.praetorian.com/blog/building-a-basic-fuzzer-with-gdb-the-five-minute-gdb-scripting-tutorial%5d)) but all of these calls fail.

```
(gdb) call (char*)malloc(4)

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00000004
0x37af2060 in strcpy ()
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (malloc) will be abandoned.
```

or
    (gdb) print (float) fabs (3.0)

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x40080000
0x37b18040 in T_CString_int64ToString ()
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (T_CString_int64ToString) will be abandoned.
```

Why would malloc access memory at the parameter "size"? Anly ideas how to fix this? Or is the gdb version simply not ready for iOS 6.X? The actual call seems to work, but internal Functions cause the failure (T_CString_int64ToString).

Comment: What happens if you try to use lldb? It's not as tried and true, but it may just work for this situation.

Comment: It seems that lldb is only supported via XCode on a MacOS System. ("Note that LLDB currently only builds out of the box on Mac OS X with Xcode"). I only have a jailbroken iPod with gdb running via SSH :/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that GDB is attempting to access an unmapped memory region, which is the address returned by the malloc call. Try attaching to a known application/process and see if the malloc call works.

Have you tried release 1821?
it's available from [CrackLords Repository](http://cracklords.info/forums/index.php?/forum-28/announcement-5-adding-our-cydia-repository/), add it to cydia to get this version
or alternatively you can follow these instructions to sign it yourself [A working GNU Debugger on iOS >= 4.3](http://www.pod2g.org/2012/02/working-gnu-debugger-on-ios-43.html)